# Проблемы с каскадной валидацией параметрова rest-запроса

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Есть rest-запрос:

```
@NewSpan("NewSpan")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponceEntity someRest(@Valid @RequestBody RestBody) {}
```

Тело запроса имеет следующую структуру:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class RestBody implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   String id;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   SomeStatus status;
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   @Valid
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   List<ChildElement> childElements;
}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class ChildElement implements Serializable {

   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   String name;
   @NotNull(message = "Errr txt")
   @Convert(converter = JsonNodeConverter.class)
   @Column(name = "content_schema", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
   JsonNode extContent;
}
```

Spring игнорирует пустые поля в `ChildElement`, но замечает их в `RestBody`. При этом, если я прогоняю объект через безовый `ValidatorImpl`, он ошибку возвращает.

Подскажите в чем проблема.

(Spring Boot - 2.1.6)

Comment: @Valid у вас на месте. А можете стектрейс ошибки предоставить?

Comment: Так проблема в том что его нет! Он считает что все хорошо и выполняет логику в теле реста.

Comment: Во-первых, не стоит гонять через REST Entity, всё же лучше сделать DTO. Во-вторых, используйте свой валидатор и валидируйте всё, что Вам необходимо. Я про спринговый интерфейс Validator сейчас говорю.